# Yii Framework : Is it a good idea for writng custom code for routing by logic?

Tags: php, yii, yii-routing

I wonder if I have some logic for my url routing, Using a custom coding php will be a better idea than using the Yii urlManager inside `protected/config/main.php`.

the "logic" mentioned above means some if{ ... }else{ ... } case, which I think keeping in the format of urlManager is a bad idea for Readability. But I am not sure is there other solution, or something I miss understand about urlManager, or may be my connect about MVC developing in Yii is not correct. So please correct me if I go wrong.

Here is what I want to do :

1. if the first parameter of url is 'admin' ,then take the 2nd parameter as controller name, take the 3rd parameter as action name, and  route to the controller locate inside the 'admin' folder.
2. if first parameter of url is 'forum' & with only one more parameter, then route to 'Forum' controller while passing the 2nd parameter into action 'index'.
3. if first parameter of url is 'forum' & with more than one more parameter, then route to 'ForumPost' controller, passing all the parameter except the first one as a array into action 'index'.
4. Except the case mentioned above, go the default way as Yii do. first parameter for controller name, 2nd parameter as action name.

P.S. Readability and easy to maintenance is my first consider so I am avoid to using .htaccess (my partner don't know about .htaccess, only php)

---

**Edit :**
I have write my rounteController (sorry, not clean code. I will break it down into functions later)

```
public function actionIndex(){



    $is_Admin = false;
    $args = func_get_args ();

    //Language handle
    $arg_1 = strtolower ($args[0]);
    if($arg_1 == 'fr' || $arg_1 == 'en' ){
        setLanguage($arg_1);
        array_shift($args);
    }

    //check if admin
    $arg_1 = strtolower ($args[0]);
    if($arg_1 == 'admin'){
        $is_Admin = true;
        array_shift($args);

        //admin index
        if(count($args) == 0){
            $this->redirect(array('admin/'));
            exit();
        }

        //controller in admin
        $controllerName = strtolower ($args[0]);
        if(count($args) == 1){

            //controller only
            $this->redirect(array('admin_'.$controllerName.'/'));
            exit();

        }elseif(count($args) == 2){

            //controller + action
            $controllerName = strtolower ($args[0]);
            $actionName     = strtolower ($args[1]);        
            $this->redirect(array('admin_'.$controllerName.'/'.$actionName));
            exit;

        }else{

            //controller + action + parameter
            $controllerName = strtolower ($args[0]);
            $actionName     = strtolower ($args[1]);
            $para           = $args[2];
            if(is_numeric ($para){

                // id parameter
                $this->redirect(array(
                    'admin_'.$controllerName.'/'.$actionName,
                    'id'=>$para;
                ));
                exit;

            }else{

                // string parameter
                $this->redirect(array(
                    'admin_'.$controllerName.'/'.$actionName,
                    'str'=>$para;
                ));
                exit;

            }
        }
    }

    //forum
    $arg_1 = strtolower ($args[0]);
    if($arg_1 == 'forum'){
        if(count($args) < 2){
            //only one more parameter after 'forum'
            //rounte to 'forum' controller 
            $cateSlug = $arg_1 = strtolower ($args[1]);
            $this->redirect(array(
                'forum/index',
                'cateSlug'=> $cateSlug)
            );
            exit();
        }else{
            //only one more parameter after 'forum'
            //rounte to 'forumPost' controller 
            $cateSlug  = strtolower ($args[1]);
            $topicSlug = strtolower ($args[2]);
            $this->redirect(array('
                forumPost/index', 
                'cateSlug'=> $cateSlug, 
                'topicSlug'=> $topicSlug)
            );
            exit();
        }
    }

    //----normal case ---

    //site index
    if(count($args) == 0){
        $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
        exit;
    }

    if(count($args) == 1){

        //controller only
        $controllerName = strtolower ($args[0]);
        $this->redirect(array($controllerName.'/'));
        exit;
    }elseif(count($args) == 2){

        //controller + action
        $controllerName = strtolower ($args[0]);
        $actionName     = strtolower ($args[1]);        
        $this->redirect(array($controllerName.'/'.$actionName));
        exit;
    }else{

        //controller + action + parameter
        $controllerName = strtolower ($args[0]);
        $actionName     = strtolower ($args[1]);
        $para           = $args[2];
        if(is_numeric ($para){

            // id paremeter
            $this->redirect(array(
                $controllerName.'/'.$actionName,
                'id'=>$para;
            ));
            exit;
        }else{

            // string paremeter
            $this->redirect(array(
                $controllerName.'/'.$actionName,
                'str'=>$para;
            ));
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2 :**

[image]

[image]

**The $this->redirect() function is not direct to the controller.... It's still pass thought urlManager .....**

Comment: I didn't get confirmed, But it may be need to show the Language in the url too (for the user can bookmark and share). If it does, may be the first parameter is for Language,however it will not do any routing, just set a value on session.

Comment: "my partner don't know about `.htaccess`, only php" ... if you feel that using `.htaccess` is a better solution, it may be worth considering educating them.

Comment: yes, thank you. I agreed with you, but Mr. Practical is not so friendly to me.

Comment: please give me more comment, as there's not much view in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have realize modules:

admin;
forum;

and then you can use:

```
site.com/admin/ - admin panel

site.com/forum/ - forum
```

and also

```
site.com/site/index will be home page
```

it just first thing which I decided, this variant will right if you will have forum in one application with your web app.

Comment: I think you are trying to show the url the user will enter in my case.  May be you can use "add comment" next time .My question is about how to make it : using custom code ? or urlManager ?